# opencv: crop image on the GPU side

Tags: python, opencv, opencl, gpu

To speed up some operations I transfered image to GPU memory. After some processing I have to crop some area:

```
image = cv2.UMat(image)
...
crop = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]
```

The problem is that it is not possible to slice image inside GPU memory. Above code will raise error: "UMat object is not subscriptable". The solution I found is to transfer image back to numpy object, than slice it, and transfer back to GPU:

```
image = cv2.UMat(image)
...
image = image.get()
crop = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]
crop = cv2.UMat(crop)
...
```

But above solution looks costly, as transferring data to/from GPU memory takes time. I have a feeling that there is a way to crop an image within GPU memory. Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some study of UMat class source code and tests I found this solution:

```
crop = cv2.UMat(image, [y0, y1], [x0, x1])
```

Comment: on opencv 4.0.0 I get the following error:

clip0 = cv2.UMat(umat0, [win_i, win_i+steps[0]], [win_j,win_j+steps[1]])
TypeError: UMat() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 0):

```
def crop_umat(umat, height, width, left=0, top=0):
    return cv.UMat(umat, [top, height+top], [left, width+left])
```